# Modify variables in an instance from another class Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, instance

I simplified this for brevity; hopefully this example isn't actually functional. I'm creating and doing things with a variable, then I'm having another class do some stuff, then that class refers back to the original and tells it to do more stuff with that variable.

I've done exactly this with views. I simply pass the activity and then when I need to use it I use `activity.findViewById(id)` to do stuff. With variables, you can't just do activity.variable. I tried using a getter (as shown in this example), but maybe I'm still just doing it wrong or it can't be done how I'd like:

```
public class MyActivity {

    private int test;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
        test = 5;
        int data = 100;
        //Pass something to it
        new NotAnActivity().func(MyActivity.this,data);
    }

    public int gettest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void func(Activity instance, int response) {
        int test = new MyActivity().gettest();
        //Do stuff with test
    }
}

public class NotAnActivity {

    public void func(Activity instance, int data) {
        //Do stuff with data
        int response = 20;
        //Try to pass information back
        new MyActivity().func(instance,response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a `activity.gettest()` because you're passing the superclass Activity between classes. To have access to the `gettest()` method you need to pass the specific child activity (`MyActivity` extends `Activity`, pass `MyActivity` instead of `Activity`) or you can cast to your specific activity.

```
((MyActivity)activity).getter();
```

So here, instead of:

```
public void func(Activity instance, int data) {
        //Do stuff with data
        int test = ((MyActivity)instance).gettest();
    }
```

or

```
public void func(MyActivity instance, int data) {
        //Do stuff with data
        int test = instance.gettest();
    }
```

It's not a good idea to instantiate your activities yourself **new A()**

Comment: Ah, now I understand what I was missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int test;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    test = 5;
    int data = 100;
    new NotAnActivity().func(this,data);
}

public int gettest() {
    return test;
}

public void func(MainActivity instance, int response) {
    //int test = new MainActivity().gettest();
    int test = instance.gettest();
    Log.v("variable", "test = " + test);
}
}

class NotAnActivity {

public void func(MainActivity instance, int data) {
    //Do stuff with data
    int response = 20;
    //Try to pass information back
    instance.func(instance,response);
}
}
```

You can try it. Your mistake is **[new MyActivity()]**